# Javascript drowdown problem - Drupal

Tags: javascript, drupal, drop-down-menu

I need to debug javascript voor IE on [this website](http://pentatone.pentatone.them.pro). When you see the homepage, the dropdown's in the header (Select a Composer and Select a Orchestra) show properly. But when you see a [detail page](http://pentatone.pentatone.them.pro/russian-violin-concertos) in IE, the dropdown's are fully shown... I don't know shit about javascript. 
Does anyone have an idea where to look? It's a Drupal website with a lot of javascript...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, I figured out the problem. I had to optimize the CSS and JS structure in the Drupal admin menu!

Answer (score 1):

From what i can tell it isnt loading the

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/themes/garland/minnelli/custom/css/fg.dropdown.css?R" />
```

properly. Cannot find why tho. Hate devtools is so useless for IE :(

Anyway the dropdown has the state Hidden when isnt being dropped down, but seems IE cant access this style and hide it from what i can tell.

Comment: Ok, very interesting... How did you figured this out? :) Yeah, IE, didn't like it ether... But what the client wants, the client gets! Thanks a lot by the way!